# Cómo concatenar dos valores en Linq y mostrarlos en un combobox

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy tratando de llenar un `combobox` con dos valores usando `linq`, pero me quede estancado en el momento de asignar los valores al `combobox`

`Consulta Linq`

```
using (SSF_PRUEBASEntities entidades = new SSF_PRUEBASEntities())
            {
                var query = from pr in entidades.un_terceprove.ToList()
                            join c in entidades.un_tercegener
                            on new { codigo = pr.tprtercegener, compania = pr.tprcompania } equals new { codigo = c.tgecodigo, compania = c.tgecompania }
                            where pr.tprcompania == "01" && pr.eobcodigo == "AC"
                            select new
                            {
                                concatenado = c.tgenit + ", " + c.tgenombcomp
                            };

                //c.tgenit, c.tgenombcomp 
                List<un_tercegener> proveedores = new List<un_tercegener>();
                foreach (var result in query)
                {
                    proveedores.Add(new un_tercegener { tgenit = result.tgenit, tgenombcomp = result.tgenombcomp });
                }
                //Insertar proveedores
                proveedores.Add(new un_tercegener { tgenit = "-1", tgenombcomp = "Listado Proveedores" });
                cmbRemitente.DisplayMemberPath = "concatenado";
                cmbRemitente.SelectedValuePath = "tgenit";
                cmbRemitente.ItemsSource = proveedores.OrderBy(O => O.tgenombcomp).ToList();
                cmbRemitente.SelectedValue = "-1";
            }
        }
```

***Donde me quede es en esta parte:***

```
foreach (var result in query)
                {
                    proveedores.Add(new un_tercegener { tgenit = result.tgenit, tgenombcomp = result.tgenombcomp });
                }
```

Ya que que el combobox se carga, pero carga los valores en blanco.
Pero con un punto de interrupción logré observar que si consulta los valores solo que no los he podido asignar.

Agradezco sus aportes.

Comment: qué `ComboBox` queres llenar? aclará siempre si estas trabajando en windows forms,wpf, o bajo qué framework estás trabajando

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Gracias por responder, el `combobox` es el `cmbRemitente` y estoy usando `wpf`

Comment: Tu clase `un_tercegener` tiene una propiedad que se llama `concatenado` ?

Comment: No, es una variable que utilice para poder guardar el valor concatenado allí, ¿lo estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: En la primer query, cual sería el Id dentro del combo? Osea, mostrarías lo que se encuentra en `concatenado`, pero cual sería el valor de cada uno de esos registros? Qué valor pretendes obtener?

Comment: El id seria `tgenit` muestro el valor concatenado pero el valor a guardar es `tgenit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está en que en la clase `un_tercegener` no se define la propiedad `concatenado`, que le estas asignando al `ComboBox` como `DisplayMemberPath`.

No queda del todo claro porque recorres el resultado de la query y lo pones en otra lista, ya en la query tenes toda la información que necesitas para llenar el `ComboBox`

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
using (SSF_PRUEBASEntities entidades = new SSF_PRUEBASEntities())
{
    var query = from pr in entidades.un_terceprove.ToList()
        join c in entidades.un_tercegener
        on new { codigo = pr.tprtercegener, compania = pr.tprcompania } equals new { codigo = c.tgecodigo, compania = c.tgecompania }
        where pr.tprcompania == "01" && pr.eobcodigo == "AC"
        select new
        {
            //En el objeto anónimo que definis agrego el Id
            Id = c.tgenit,
            concatenado = c.tgenit + ", " + c.tgenombcomp
        }.ToList();

    //Ahora si el DisplayMemberPath es concatenado
    cmbRemitente.DisplayMemberPath = "concatenado";
    //y el SelectedValuePath es Id
    cmbRemitente.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
    //e ItemsSource es query
    cmbRemitente.ItemsSource = query;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ejemplo me funciono muy bien!

Comment: @BrianVelez entendiste cual era el problema?